# Can ultrasound be used to determine distance without line of sight?

Tags: ultrasound, distance, phase-shift

Is it possible to determine the distance between 2 devices (using phase shift, time of flight or any other method) without line of sight?

In the affirmative case what's the precision and accuracy for distances below 50cm, and where could I get good information about that particular method?

Comment: What are you trying to go through? Depending what it is, attenuation frequencies may be different. Though, you may be able to do it indirectly through reflections, but you'll need a very complex setup. In other words, more detail is needed about your particular case.

Comment: Sound propagates round corners, so theoretically it's not impossible - but it will give you the *propagation* distance not the "straight line" distance.

Comment: I'm trying to go through an human ankle, to measure the leg stride. I was looking for a simple and practical to use solution.

Comment: I don't think ultrasound is an appropriate use for that. I'd look at more round-about methods of getting the same information. For example, if you can figure out the distance made per stride, then you can calculate the stride with information like the users leg height/length.

Comment: The usual technique for measuring stride length is to use a gyro and accelerometer.

Comment: I know it's off topic but doesn't using sensor fusion between a gyro and an accelerometer only measures the direction of an object and not the relative distance?

Comment: I believe you can use the gyroscope to tell when the leg is in a stride position and use the acceleration impulse time to get the time it is in that position. I believe you can derive distance from the accelerometer via a method called the double integration method... normally the error associated is too large, but you're only interested in distances between each stride. Technically, with just the impulse time and the distance calculation, you should be able to get stride length.

Comment: You can use ultrasound through an ankle, or through air, but probably not practically both as energy will propagate poorly across the transition.  However, you shouldn't need to go through the ankle, just use transducers with a wide enough angle to see the other foot in front or behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both devices could both send and receive... then they could talk to figure it out.

One would send a reference pulse, and the other would respond as quickly as it could. As long as your timing on processing and sending was fairly predictable (low jitter), the first device could take the total time from sending the reference to receiving the response, subtract a constant processing delay that would be very easy to experimentally measure, and arrive at the trip time.

This would not give a direct distance, but the distance going around any obstacles... unless the obstacles were particularly transparent to ultrasound. Even then, the difference in propogation speed through different mediums would mess with your results. Practically, it would most likely nearly always result in the through-air trip time around obstacles.

Comment: And worse, indirect paths almost always involve multipath effects.